# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Pardon my lack of knowledge as I am learning RoR.

when I run `bundle update` I get this error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
      railties (= 4.2.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
        actionpack (= 4.2.2) x64-mingw32

    rails (= 4.2.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
      railties (= 4.2.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
        actionpack (= 4.2.2) x64-mingw32

    rails (= 4.2.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
      railties (= 4.2.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
        actionpack (= 4.2.2) x64-mingw32

    refinerycms (~> 3.0) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 3.0.0, which
depends on
        actionpack (< 5.0, >= 4.2.3) x64-mingw32

C:\Ruby200-x64\my_new_application>ruby --v
ruby: invalid option --v  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)
```

Here is my ruby version

```
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x64-mingw32]
```

actually `rails` was working perfectly until I decided to install [refinerycms from here.](http://www.refinerycms.com/download) following the guideline posted on that page.

I searched this error and people suggested `bundle update` or `bundle install` but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using Rails 4.2.2 which uses ActionPack 4.2.2 while Refinery CMS wants at least 4.2.3. If you update Rails (probably need to adapt your `Gemfile` to use a newer version, like `~> 4.2.3`), everything should be fine.

Comment: As I wrote, you will need to update your `Gemfile` with a more appropriate version descriptor. It should say, somewhere at the top, `gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.3'`. Then save it and run `bundle update`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the version of refinerycms you are using depends on Rails 4.2.3 and you are using 4.2.2. Can you try either upgrading Rails to 4.2.3 or downgrading Refinerycms to one that supports 4.2.2?

Comment: here http://www.refinerycms.com/ they say `Ruby on Rails CMS that supports Rails 4.2`

Comment: It is correct but not complete. It supports 4.2.3 and above. Just try it.